# Upload File Using Url to Box content-api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, box-api, boxapiv2

I did some research and i couldn't find any information regarding this,

I know that box content-api call to upload needs to be form-data

is there way to upload file via giving a url of the file?

like for example i want to save this file,

https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

without downloading it on to the computer (client side). and than uploading it with api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to upload a file with the Box API using a URL to a file.

When calling the [Upload File endpoint for the Box API](https://docs.box.com/reference#upload-a-file), you have to specify the file's location on your local machine or server.

Comment: Is this feature on the roadmap ?

Comment: @Murtza Is this feature available now? I don't have the file on the machine. It's uploaded to cloud storage directly.